# How do I make Ctrl+A to not shift cursor to the beginning of the text line?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> shortcut works good but when I select some input text and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, the cursor returns to the beginning of text line instead of previously selected text in the input text.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> also not working in GEdit.

I'm using ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: By default, Ctrl+a work as expected in 18.04 LTS on my system. Have you set different keybindings?

Comment: In fact what i did is go to Tweaks -> Keyboard & Mouse  -> Additional Layout Options -> Switching to another layout -> select Alt+Shift. I read some answers talking about putting my default language on top (In Region and Language area), but  this also not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem after upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 19.10 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>. 
 I fixed the issue by going into *Tweaks* -> *Keyboard & Mouse* and desactivate *Emacs Input*.

Comment: **it's worked well !** 
I really appreciate your help thank you !